# путь к новой картинке

Tags: javascript

Есть img. Нужно чтобы пользователь при нажатии на эту картинку мог выбрать со своего устройства собственную картинку.
как сделать при нажатии на картинку, чтобы появлялось предложение выбрать путь к новой картинке?
нужно без jQuery

Comment: Вы уже задали четыре вопроса, на которые получили пять ответов. Обратите внимание на значки "галочка" слева от ответов. Они предназначены для Вас - автора вопросов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например так:

```
<input type="image" src="images/img.jpg" alt="Submit Image" />
```

Вариант:

```css
input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label for="fileinput">
  <img src="http://s1.iconbird.com/ico/2013/12/517/w128h1281386955323camera3.png" alt="Submit Image" >
</label>

<input name='fileinput' id="fileinput"  type="file" accept="image/*" capture />
```

Comment: при использовании этого кода ничего не изменится.
повторюсь, при нажатии на картинку пользователю предлагается установить путь к своей фотографии на своем устройстве. эта фотография будет вместо той, что стоит изначально. типо автара, как в вк.

Comment: Как вы хотите показывать картинку другим, не загрузив её, если она хранится локально у пользователя?

Comment: Посмотрите, добавил вариант. Это то, что Вы хотели?

Comment: да, это близко, но если я нажимаю на картинку, мне предлагает выбрать путь к новому img, я выбираю новый img, но она не устанавливается в замен предыдущей

Comment: Каким образом Вы будете отправлять картинку на сервер?  Если использовать Ajax, то в обратном ответе от сервера, вы можете отправить ссылку на загруженное изображение и заменить им существующее.    Можно конечно и сразу заменить, но какой смысл? после перезагрузки страницы это изображение просто исчезнет.